# How to find the area of overlap of two quarter circles

Tags: geometry

The question is to find the area of a shaded region. The shaded region is the overlap of two quarter circles both of which have two of their radii on the edge of a 15x15cm square. Both quarter circles are across from eachother so all interior sides of the square are touched, but it is only the area of the overlap that is important. The overlap is shaped like an oval with the top and the bottom pointed instead of rounded. Thanks

Comment: write an equation in the form area of the square = area of quarter circle + area of quarter circle minus area of overlap.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the areas of the quarter circles separately, you will obtain the sum of the area of the square and the area of the overlapping region. Subtract the area of the square from this sum to get the area of the overlapping region.

Thus

Area of overlapping region = $2*\frac{\pi}{4}*15^2 - 15^2=15^2(\frac{\pi}{2}-1)cm^2$